# TSQL - Transform addresses on different rows to one row for each customer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have come across this roadblock today. Maybe due to the lack of sleep/coffee, I just can't figure out how to get around.

We need a query that looks through the address table and returns both the delivery and the billing addresses on one row for the same customer.

The table structures are of course greatly simplified to include only the pertinent columns.

The address table:

```
CustID Address          AddressType
-----------------------------------
1      3 Marsh Road     D
1      5 Bog Street     B
2      4 Peat Close     D
3      1 Swamp Crescent D
3      5 Moor Avenue    B
4      6 Wetland Place  D
```

The primary key is (custID, AddressType). AddressType values: D = Delivery address; B = Billing address. Every CustID has a Delivery Adress, but not everyone has a Billing address.

Now what I want to achieve is to transform the above into below based on the AddressType field, via a query, so that we have this (if no Billing, then use Delivery address):

```
CustID DelAddress       BillAddress
---------------------------------------
1      3 Marsh Road     5 Bog Street
2      4 Peat Close     4 Peat Close
3      1 Swamp Crescent 5 Moor Avenue
4      6 Wetland Place  6 Wetland Place
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) will help you when something exists in A and maybe in B. Join to the Address table twice, once for Delivery, once for an optional billing. Use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to replace a null value with something else

```
SELECT
    CustID
,   D.Address AS DelAddress
,   COALESCE(B.Address, D.Address) AS BillAddress
FROM
    ADDRESS D
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ADDRESS B
        ON B.CustId = D.CustId
        AND B.AddressType = 'B'
WHERE
    D.AddressType = 'D'
```